Write to TextView from another class
I am new to Java/Android programming, coming from Visual Basic.
I have defined in acitvity_main.xml a TextView. I can write it from the MainActivity.java. But I have a button defined in here which is calling another class "Routines". From there, I want to write to the TextView defined in the activity_main.xml using the context (like the msgBox in this java class). Unfortunately, I don't get it to work.
I read many posts already, but I don't get, or understand, the code.
This is my code:
Main class
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Routines rtns = new Routines();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //code
    }

    public void bt_find_clicked(View view)
    {
        rtns.findData(getApplicationContext());
        //rtns.msgBox(getApplicationContext(),"Hello");
    }
}

Second class
public class Routines extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static void findData(Context mContext)
    {
    TextView txtView = new TextView(Context mContext);
        txtView = txtView.findViewById(R.id.tb_reservations);
        txtView.setText("Hello");
    }

    public static void msgBox( Context mContext, String msg)
    {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText( mContext,msg, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}


You cannot access activities like that, if you want to send something to a new activity you need to send it in an intent
Intent intent = Intent(context, Routines.class)
intent.putExtra("myData", "Text from MainActivity") //put data in the intent
startActivity(intent)  //Shows the Routine activity

Then in your Routines class you would get the data in your onCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout_xml)
    String dataFromOtherActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("myData") // get data from intent
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.myTextView)
    tv.setText(dataFromOtherActivity)
}

You also didnt set your MainActivity layout either
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.acitvity_main)
}

I was trying to find you a basic example from android documentation but apparently they only have Compose example now for some dumb reason and not xml views like you are using.
It might be better to just start learning Compose rather than xml UI's if you are just starting out. You can find a tutorial for making your first Compose app here

For a simple solution I bring back the reading and writing of spinners, textviews etc. back to the mainactivity. Also I start reading the online ebook you sent me.
